# how to modify vector of user-defined type without changing the original vector?

Tags: copy, julia

I have a vector of any, say `A = Any[[1,2],[3,4]]`. Then, I want to create a new array, say `C::Vector{Any}` based on my elements in `A`, but without actually changing `A`. I have been trying to create a copy, `B = copy(A)`, and making changes to elements in `B` to then add to `C`, so that `A` doesn't change, but `A` keeps changing. Now you might ask me to use deep copy, but I don't want that because I still want the unchanged elements in `C` to be equal to those in `A`, i.e. `A[1] == C[1]` should return `true` if I added the first element of `A` in `C` without doing any changes. `C` could, for example, be `Any[[1,2],[3,4,5]]`.

So how do I create `C` without changing `A` at all, and also making sure that equality of unchanged elements hold?

Comment: I don't understand. If you use `C = deepcopy(A)`, then unchanged elements in `C` *will* have equality with corresponding elements in `A`. For example: `A = Any[[1,2],[3,4]] ; C = deepcopy(A) ; C[2] = [4,5] ; A[1] == C[1]` <- returns `true`.

Comment: I agree that this request seems self-contradictory. Do you want changes to the elements to remain the same or not? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: sorry, if my question was confusing. I got it working now. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Try `similar(A)`. It does initialize a new array based on the characteristics of the array on the argument.

Anyway with `copy(A)` as you mention on the post it does work for me. I've to mention that I use `v0.5-dev` version of Julia.

I should say that your question is not completely clear, but if with my answer is enough, then have happy coding. If not, I'd try to answer clearer.